# How to show and hide a Textbox in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react js. I'm trying to show and hide a textbox on a button click.Is there any function available for that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no function for that. You can hide/show by applying basic css. You should post some of your code, so others can better help you out. I have no idea where you're at with your code, so it's hard to provide a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there any predefined functions for hiding things on reactjs. However, you can use the showResults:false or true method.  I have use same technique for my project to hide the form. For example, from this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/3369/

```
    render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" onClick={this.onClick} />
            { this.state.showResults ? <Results /> : null }
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden attribute of Input Text box. You can enter some condition or a variable in curly braces. This Boolean variable can help decide to hide this or not.
Here is an example,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).